# Sharepoint 2007 => Search => Sorting

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I apologize if the question already exists... 
Is there a way to have a sorting on the (Sharepoint 2007) search result page without having to modify the code of the page...? ANd how, if so?

I am trying to sort on title when the result is loaded:
[image]

It should be something simple.., but I am new to sharepoint.. so I appreciate any help..

Thanks!!
Katya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groetjes Katya, this really **should** be simple. It is not, though... ;-)

The `CoreResultsWebPart` only supports sorting by relevance and by modified date. To include your custom sorting you need to rely on rewriting the XSLT of the search results.

There is a nice how-to here:
[HOW-TO: Group search results by a property value in SharePoint](http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/morse_matt/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=52), but it surely involves writing XSLT "code".

It might be easier for you to rely on using a third-party search result webpart, such as the WildCardSearchWebPart: [Announcing custom sort order support for WildcardSearchWebPart](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/05/20/announcing-custom-sort-order-support-for-wildcardsearchwebpart.aspx) or even more powerful: [MOSS faceted search](http://facetedsearch.codeplex.com/).

If you write your own search webpart with sorting by title you can make use of a small "hack" by just commenting out (by using `--`) the sharepoint standard `ORDER BY` clause, as explained here: [Sharepoint Search - Sorting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/b99f827d-ccd9-4455-873c-0ce76df27394).

Comment: Hmm... the problem with the XSLT solution is when you have a paging.. then the xslt doesn't work anymore.. so I am looking for a custom one...

Comment: You really are developing everything right now aren't you? Dynamics CRM, Sharepoint? ;-) If by any chance you can switch to Sharepoint 2010, you can pretty much sort by anything there. For your problem you are probably stuck with writing your own search result webpart including paging.